# Question with Linq on XML,At least one object must implement IComparable

Tags: c#, xml, linq

```
        string studentsXML =
                    @"<Students>
                        <Student>
                            <Name>Toni</Name>
                            <Age>21</Age>
                            <University>Yale</University>
                            <Semester>6</Semester>
                            <GPA>3.5</GPA>
                        </Student>
                        <Student>
                            <Name>Carla</Name>
                            <Age>17</Age>
                            <University>Yale</University>
                            <Semester>1</Semester>
                            <GPA>3.8</GPA>
                        </Student>
                        <Student>
                            <Name>Leyla</Name>
                            <Age>19</Age>
                            <University>Beijing Tech</University>
                            <Semester>3</Semester>
                            <GPA>3.0</GPA>
                        </Student>
                        <Student>
                            <Name>Frank</Name>
                            <Age>25</Age>
                            <University>Beijing Tech</University>
                            <Semester>10</Semester>
                            <GPA>2.0</GPA>
                        </Student>
                        <Student>
                            <Name>Ken</Name>
                            <Age>29</Age>
                            <University>Beijing Tech</University>
                            <Semester>10</Semester>
                            <GPA>4.0</GPA>
                        </Student>
                    </Students>";
```

**Above is the XML code and I'm trying to sort it in order of age using linq so it should be able to display name and age in order at the end.
Code below is showing error. Would appreciate it if someone could give me input on this.
I'm actually still learning right now and was trying out stuff but obviously it is not working. **

```
        XDocument studentsXdoc1 = new XDocument();
        studentsXdoc1 = XDocument.Parse(studentsXML);

        var testing = from student in studentsXdoc1.Descendants("Student")
                      orderby student.Element("Age")
                      select new
                      {
                          Name = student.Element("Name"),
                          Age = student.Element("Age")
                      };
        foreach(var i in testing)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }



        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: With xml linq it is better to cast than to use value.  Value when object is null can have exceptions.  So use : Name =(string) student.Element("Name") and Age = (int)student.Element("Age")

Comment: Please change the title to a question and integrate the error message into the text below. The error message tells you, that it is not able to order by "Age", because it does not know how to compare those elements. So far, it is not secified, that it contains numbers. So type casts, like suggested by @jdweng may help.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.Value` to `student.Element("Age")` to get the value of the element

```
var testing = from student in studentsXdoc1.Descendants("Student")
                orderby int.Parse(student.Element("Age").Value)
                select new
                {
                    Name = student.Element("Name").Value,
                    Age = student.Element("Age").Value
                };
```

The value of age needs to be parsed when ordering by age.